# SQL batch update - rollback on "CREATE TABLE"?

Tags: java, sql, batch-file, rollback

I have a method for upgrading DB:

```
private void executeUpdateBatch(String... sql) throws SQLException {
    JdbcConnection connJbdc = new JdbcConnectionImpl();
    Connection conn = connJbdc.getConnection();
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();

    for(String s : sql) {
        st.addBatch(s);
    }

    try {
        // execute the batch
        int[] updateCounts = st.executeBatch();
      } catch (BatchUpdateException e) {
        int[] updateCounts = e.getUpdateCounts();
        checkUpdateCounts(updateCounts);
        try {
          conn.rollback();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
        }

        throw new SQLException(e);
      }
      // since there were no errors, commit
      conn.commit();

      st.close();
      conn.close();
}
```

And upgrade method:

```
public void upgradeTo5() throws SQLException {
    executeUpdateBatch("CREATE TABLE project ("
            + "id INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, "
            + "title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "
            + "date_from DATE NULL, date_to DATE NULL,"
            + "active BIT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id))",
            "INSERT INTO project(titlea) VALUES('test1')");
}
```

An error is in `INSERT` just for testing rollback.

Well, the problem now is that it does not rollbacks `CREATE TABLE project`. Table is InnoDB. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by MySQL/InnoDB. All DDL statements (`CREATE TABLE`, `ALTER TABLE`, `CREATE INDEX`, `DROP ...`) always happen outside of transaction control.

This is a weak point that IIRC Postgres can handle better, but with MySQL you have to work around that by reverting the changes yourself in case of rollbacks.